# Find vowels in a string

Tags: c, string, scanf

Given below is my code for finding vowels in a given string:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char str[100];
    int i, str_length;

    //scanf("%[^\n]%*c", &str[100]);
    fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin);
    str_length = strlen(str);
    for (i = 0; i < str_length; i++) {
        if (str[i] == 'a' || str[i] == 'e' ||
            str[i] == 'i' || str[i] == 'o' || 
            str[i] == 'u' || str[i] == 'A' ||
            str[i] == 'E' || str[i] == 'I' ||
            str[i] == 'O' || str[i] == 'U')
        {
            printf("Vowels in the string are: %c \n", str[i]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I just wanna know, why `scanf("%[^\n]%*c",&str[100])` is not working in my code?
cause I tried executing my program multiple times using `scanf` but it didn't worked.

And after using `fgets` I got the desired output.

So, can anyone help me to understand, where I am wrong!!

Comment: `&str[100]` is a pointer to the 101st element in the array, one past the end. You probably meant just `str` which decays to a pointer to the first element.

Comment: ==> `scanf("%[^\n]%*c", str)` ... but it's better (**way, way better**) to use `fgets()`

Comment: *"And after using fgets I got the desired output."* - And that's why you use that function instead

Comment: And activate your warnings

Comment: @klutt These kinds of errors are usually not caught by compilers. These don't usually do a check of the kind "was the memory pointed to by this expression allocated by the program at this point?"

Comment: @Yun True. But it's a damn good general advice. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `scanf` function call, this `&str[100]` takes a pointer to `str`, makes it point to the element with the index 100 (which is past the end of the array), dereferences it and then takes the address of that (non-existing) element. This, most likely, leads to an attempt to an invalid write, which is probably caught by the operating system which terminates your program. In any case, the string is not written to the correct location.

Instead, you want the argument to point to the memory location of the first element of `str`, i.e.:

```
scanf("%[^\n]%*c", str);
```

That said, using `fgets` is better as it accepts an argument for the size which prevents buffer overflows. A size can also be given to `scanf`, but since it is part of the format specifier it cannot be a variable; only a hardcoded constant:

```
scanf("%99[^\n]%*c", str);
```

Note that this is for *99* elements, as there needs to be room for the null-terminator (`\0`) as well. See [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) for more info on `scanf`. But again, using `fgets` is less error prone and to be preferred.

*Some additional advice*:

- The typical signature of the `main` function, using no parameters, is `int main(void)`.
- The `scanf` version fails if the input is a single newline character. Both versions fail on no input. It is always a good idea the check the return values of input (and output) functions.
- Inside of the for-loop, you could create a copy of the current character converted to lowercase using the [tolower](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/tolower) function, and then perform only the lowercase comparisons. I.e.:

```
for (i = 0; i < str_length; i++) {
    char ch = tolower(str[i]);
    if (ch == 'a' || ch == 'e' || ch == 'i' || ch == 'o' || ch == 'u')
        printf("Vowels in the string are: %c \n", str[i]);
}
```

- Another option is to replace the comparisons in the if-statement with a call to [`strchr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strchr), which makes the program a bit more generic and scalable (one string is more easily changed than multiple comparisons):

```
char ch = tolower(str[i]);
if (strchr("aeiou", ch) != NULL)
    printf("Vowels in the string are: %c \n", str[i]);
```

Comment: can you please explain ``` Inside of the for-loop, you could create a copy of the current character, convert it to lowercase using the tolower function, and then perform only the lowercase comparisons.``` this point in brief. It will be more helpful for me if you provide me the code clarifying your idea.

Comment: @VaibhavKatre Sure! I've added a code example to the answer. The `tolower` function keeps lowercase characters as they are, and converts uppercase characters to lowercase. Now, only half the number of comparisons are needed. Note that the `printf` function still uses `str[i]`, so it will still print the case as it appeared in the input.

Comment: @VaibhavKatre I just added another alternative.

Answer (score 0):

```
# This is my different solution to this question #



char vowels[] = "AEIOUaeiou";
int vowel = 0, consonants = 0, space = 0;
for (int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++)
{
    if (str[i] == ' ')
    {
        space++;
    }

    for (int j = 0; vowels[j] != '\0'; j++)
    {
        if (vowels[j] == str[i])
        {
            vowel++;
        }
    }
}
consonants = strlen(str) - (vowel + space);
```